# Insert a calculated row into a data table, with multiple columns

Tags: r

I am looking to build a "Calculated Item" row into a dataframe with multiple columns.  I can do this in excel PIVOT TABLE using Calculated Item, so I assume there is way to do this in R.

I have a column for PERIODICITY that includes "CURRENT" and "YEAR AGO" in rows.  I would like to ADD a row that calculates % CHG, while maintaining the Summary level of other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.) ALso, by `%CHG` do you mean the percent change between the two columns `CURRENT` and `YEAR AGO`? And if yes, does it have to be a *percentage*?

Answer (score 0):

With the test data created at the end, here is a base R one-liner. Note the use of the new anonymous function declaration, `\(x)`. This is only valid starting with R v. 4.1.0. For R previous versions use `function(x)`.

```
df1$PERC_CHG <- apply(df1[c("YEAR_AGO", "CURRENT")], 1, \(x) diff(x)/x[1] * 100)
```

---

### Data

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 10
df1 <- data.frame(CURRENT = runif(n, 10, 100), 
                  YEAR_AGO = runif(n, 10, 100),
                  X = rnorm(n))
```